# Wordpress Blank White Page for Login

Tags: wordpress

When I go to the /wp-login.php portion of my Wordpress site I get a blank white screen. In fact, throughout the entire domain I get blank white screen. Also, I can't even connect to the server via FTP (tried with other FTP accts to make sure not FTP client). Is this an issue with the host or my WP? Not even sure how to fix it if it's on my end cuz I can't even login to FTP or to the Admin Dashboard! Any help = appreciated.

Comment: I think this should be on serverfault.  The blank script is because there is a fatal php error and your server is configured not to display errors.  You should turn on logging of errors to a logfile in the php.ini

The FTP issue is likely unrelated and should be asked on server fault as a separate question.  Make sure the daemon is running and there are no firewall issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this exact same problem when people upgrade their WP install, but do not turn off plugins. The fix is usually simple. FTP/SSH in, rename old plugins folder, create a new empty one and reload WP page.

However, since you are saying that you can't even FTP into your server, this sounds like an outage on your providers side. Perhaps it also affected their database server.

Call them up and see if it is something on their end.

Comment: what the hell, i did not even notice that this question is over 3 months old. FAIL.

Comment: don't blame yourself, blame Server Fault. It shouldn't have popped up on the main page if it is over 3 months old and the OP hasn't bothered to create an account here.

Answer (score 2):

Contact your hosting support.

That's what they're for.

The WP issue could be many different things, they will have access to logs and be able to (hopefully) tell you pretty quickly.

The FTP problem is also something your host will need to help you with.